# Reading emails from gmail by subject

Tags: c#, email, gmail, attachment

I want to read from my gmail , I want to search for the email subject("subject"), it includes in it an attachment (photo) , I want to get the photo as Image and use it .

I tried to use MailRepository class, from here :
http://mailsystem.codeplex.com/

but it reads all the emails in my gmail ,and the program stucks.

I need an effective way for my purpose ,

thanx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out how to achieve that :

First of all , one needs to add reference called : OpenPop

```
    public static byte[] GetUserImage(string image_name)
    {
        Pop3Client c = new Pop3Client();

        c.Connect("pop.gmail.com", 995, true);
        c.Authenticate("your gmail", "password");
        for (int i = c.GetMessageCount(); i >= 1; i--)
        {
            OpenPop.Mime.Message mess = c.GetMessage(i);
            if (mess.Headers.Subject.Equals(image_name))
            {
               return mess.MessagePart.MessageParts[1].Body;//this to get attachment
                                            **OR:**
               return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(mess.MessagePart.Body);//this to get text
            }

        }
        return null ;
    }
```